# Alignment of Divs

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align two social feedback buttons as below:

```
<div>
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://myaddress/<?php echo $reference; ?>" data-count="none" data-dnt="true">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>

<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://myaddress/<?php echo $reference; ?>" data-type="button">
</div>
</div>
```

The problem is, the buttons keep getting displayed like this:
[image]

For some reason they are not aligned vertically. What I want, is for them to be down near the bottom left corner of the page, and separated by an adjustable number of pixels and of course, vertically aligned. In the future, I may add more buttons. What is the best solution for this?

I have tried a number of things with divs and CSS to no avail. The last time I had to do any of this it was all done with tables but that is old-hat now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a fan of any of these answers as they don't tackle the problems that you have.

You actually already mentioned a fix yourself for the vertical alignment of the buttons. The easiest fix would be to just add a `vertical-align` attribute to the twitter class as so:

```
.twitter-share-button
{
    vertical-align: bottom;
    width: 90px !important;
}
```

The width `!important` tag is an unfortunate solution to the fact that twitter injects an iframe into your html and makes it very hard to style normally. I have made a jsfiddle for you to see the results [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wfLMm/). Adjusting the width like this is the only thing that will change the padding between the two buttons.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I was thinking about 'forcing' a vertical-align on the twitter button but it was way down my list. My thoughts were that I must be doing something wrong in the first place if this were required. I definitely need to read up more on CSS and HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet for a quick fix is to use position:relative on whichever button you want to move slightly. You can then set top:5px, left:5px or whatever values you like on the div to tweak its position relative to where it was.

Comment: I'll give this a shot also thanks. But what is the position relative to exactly? I.e.: where is the origin?

Comment: The origin is the position on screen where the button would be rendered if it was display:block, aka. where it is right now.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to place your buttons in a list (ul-li). Then you can set li's css to "display: inline-block", and play with li's height/padding in your css.

Comment: I've put: ul li {
  display:inline-block;
  height:20px;
} and then I've wrapped the buttons in: <ul> <li> </li> <li> </li> <ul> but still the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Your missing a `</div>`
I'm not sure if you wanted to have nested div or just 2 divs, guessing 2 divs, so:

```
<div>
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://myaddress/<?php echo $reference; ?>" data-count="none" data-dnt="true">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
</div>
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://myaddress/<?php echo $reference; ?>" data-type="button">
</div>
```

I see you want nested div, so the problem wasn't missing  closer. Can you provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

### In CSS:

```
#footer {       
    width: 100%;
    /* Places the button-bar on the bottom of the page. */
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    /* ------------------------------------------------ */
  }

  .button {
    float: left;
    /* 
        First number == margin for the top AND the bottom.
        Second number == margin for the left AND the right.
    */
    margin: 50px 20px;
   }
```

### In HTML:

```
<!-- Make a surrounding footer-div! -->
<div id="footer">
  <!-- Use a CSS-Class for your buttons! -->
  <div id="twitter" class="button">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" 
       data-url="http://myaddress/<?php echo $reference; ?>" 
       data-count="none" data-dnt="true">Tweet</a>        
  </div>

  <div id="facebook" class="button">
    <div class="fb-share-button" 
         data-href="http://myaddress/" 
         data-type="button">Facebook-Button</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Copy and paste my code into a page and accustom it to your needs!